# Rename [world-in-conflict-sa] to [world-in-conflict-soviet-assault] or [world-in-conflict]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

I'd like to propose renaming the tag for World in Conflict: Soviet Assault (an expansion pack for World in Conflict) from [world-in-conflict-sa](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-in-conflict-sa) to [world-in-conflict-soviet-assault](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-in-conflict-soviet-assault).

Alternatively, since there are only 3 questions and 2 of them mention the base game, it could be worth renaming to [world-in-conflict](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-in-conflict) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've renamed it to [world-in-conflict-soviet-assault](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/world-in-conflict-soviet-assault).